# JavaScript: Use a wildcard to select all child elements from a PARENT element

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to select **ALL child elements** from `<div id="VidContainer">` who's ID's pattern is `abc-` and then a randomly generated number, followed by `-container`. Ej, `"abc-985224562456540-container"`

**Because the numbers in the middle are randomly generated,  a loop won't work.** When the numbers have more than 10 digits, JS's engine enters into an "eternal loop" and the browser crashes.

**After selecting the elemnets**, I need to delete all `<div` found, with the matching pattern.

What would be the wildcard JavaScript needs to use to select them? 
And what would be the best approach to delete those elements?

**Dummy HTML**:

```
<div id="VidContainer">
  ...some more html...
  <div id="abc-13-container">Text 13</div>
  ...some more html...
  <div id="abc-9999-container">Text 10</div>
  ...some more html...
  <div id="abc-21540540640-container">Text 19</div>
  ...some more html...
</div>
```

I got most of the code. I just can't find a way to get the child element's ID (`wildcard`)

```
//Defind element ID
var elementID = "abc" + wildcard + "-container";
var parent = document.getElementById("VidContainer");

//Selet all elements to be deleted
var elements = document.getElementById(elementID);

// Removes an element from the document
while (elements.length) { parent.parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match both the start and end of an attribute with a CSS selector:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("#VidContainer>[id^=abc-][id$=-container]");

console.log("matching items to delete: ", items.length);
for (let item of items) item.remove();
```

```html
<div id="VidContainer">
  <div id="abc-13-container">Text 13</div>
  <div id="abc-9999-container">Text 10</div>
  <div id="hithere">Hi There</div>
  <div id="abc-21540540640-container">Text 19</div>
  <div id="something">Something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then, all I have to do is to put the var `items` into the while loop: `while (items.length) { parent.parentNode.removeChild(items[0]); }` ?

Comment: I added a line in the code to delete the items, but you didn't really ask in your question about removal, but *selection*. ;-) You can use the more recent `remove` method that does not need a parent reference. But you can do as you suggested as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **querySelectorAll()** with the appropriate CSS selector. Not a wildcard solution, but still:

```js
// arrow function to get all the elements 
// that are (still) part of the DOM
const getElements = () => {
  return document.querySelectorAll('#VidContainer [id^="abc-"][id$="-container"]')
}
// arrow function to DRY code removal
const remE = e => e.parentNode.removeChild(e)

// adding "self-delete on click" to all appropriate elements
getElements().forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    remE(e.target)
  })
})

// adding "delete all appropriate elements on click"
document.getElementById('clearAll').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  getElements().forEach(e => {
    remE(e)
  })
})
```

```css
[id^='abc-'][id$='-container'] {
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="VidContainer">
  ...some more html...
  <div id="abc-13-container">Text 13 - click text to remove item</div>
  ...some more html...
  <div id="abc-9999-container">Text 10 - click text to remove item</div>
  ...some more html...
  <div id="abc-21540540640-container">Text 19 - click text to remove item</div>
  ...some more html...
</div>
<button id="clearAll">Clear all</button>
```

This is a solution that has all the functions for correct removal (one-by-one or all at once).